# TFS efetua Merge Automático sem Verificar Conflitos

Tags: c#, team-foundation-server, visual-studio-2012

Instalamos recentemente o TFS 2012 para controlarmos as versões de alguns sistemas locais, porém estamos enfrentando um problema.

Quando é solicitado um check-in de um arquivo que foi alterado, esse é salvo no TFS sem verificar a versão, ou seja, não informa se existe conflitos ou não, simplesmente sobe a versão e substitui totalmente a anterior.

Alguém sabe dizer o porquê de isso ocorrer? É alguma configuração do TFS?

Obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

Não existe merge automático, em nenhuma ferramenta de merge. Pois é o desenvolvedor que deve tomar a decisão de qual código deve ser versionado. Por isso se você alterou um código e fez o check-in, não foi feito um merge, mas simplesmente um versionamento do código, ou seja, foi guardado uma nova versão dele.

No check-in o TFS irá informar se existe um conflito quando alguém alterar a mesma linha de código que está sendo enviada para o servidor. Isso seria um merge. Pois, quando dois desenvolvedores alteram o mesmo código é necessário escolher quais linhas ou partes dela irão ser versionadas. Essa escolha, que pode ser parte de uma alteração de um desenvolvedor e parte do outro é que se dá o nome de merge.

Se a versão que está no servidor é a mesma que foi baixada anteriormente e alterada, não existe conflito. Portanto, como dito anteriormente, não existe merge, por isso parece que o TFS faz algo automáticamente, mas não é verdade.

Veja a imagem abaixo:

[image: A imagem acima mostra a tela de escolha para o merge]

Você pode escolhar uma linha ou outra na ferramenta de merge do Visual Studio, usando os checkbox ao lado do source (1) e do target (2), ou até mesmo editar a linha no quadro de result.

Para chegar até essa tela, você verá um aviso no Team Explorer o seguite aviso:

[image: "Pull completed with conflicts..." é a mensagem que avisa sobre ser preciso resolver conflitos]

Clicando no link **Resolve the conflicts**:

[image: Listagem dos arquivo com conflito]

Será mostrado no Team Explorer novamente a listagem dos arquivos com conflito, se você quiser substituir integralmente um arquivo é só escolher entre **Take Remote** ou **Keep Local**, se for necessário verificar o código e usar parte de um com outro clique no botão **Merge**.

**IMPORTANTE**:
Mantenha o Visual Studio atualizado, na versão de 2013 existia um bug em relação ao botão Merge, era preciso fazer um *workaround* para que ele ficasse habilitado quando aparecesse um conflito.

Comment: é justamente essa opção de escolher qual trecho de código será inserido no check-in, ela não aparece, não me é disponibilizado essa tela de Accept Merge.

Comment: Adicionei essa parte, veja se isto resolve a sua dúvida Luiz

Comment: "Não existe merge automático, em nenhuma ferramenta de merge.", existe no Git, que é feito em três fases. O que muda é quando tanto origem quanto destino possuem uma alteração conflituosa que pede resolução do usuário.

Comment: Não, no Git o que você está chamando de ferramenta automática é o Fast Forward, porém o processo não acontece no servidor, e sim no client. 
Ou seja, continua não sendo automático eu tenho que "querer" fazer o merge, ele acontece na máquina do desenvolvedor, porém o FF é um atalho que resolve algo que eu não precisaria interagir.
Quando digo que não existe em nenhuma é por que o check-in ou commit nunca é feito e resolvido direto, você precisa executar um passo intermediário.